# Owl carousel JS works locally but not on server

Tags: javascript, html, server, owl-carousel

My code, which is:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true,
    navText: ["&#10094;","&#10095;"],
    dots:false,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        500:{

          items:2
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1200:{
            items:4
        }
    }
})


});
</script>
```

Works perfectly when running on computer but it does not when I upload it to my server. I am experiencing this with 2 other javascripts as well.  Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: No error, it just does not display the content on the webpage